# Can't using Table Attribute when create controller with views using Entity Framework Codefirst - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

i have a problem when i declare a model with attribute:

```
[Table("Items")]
  public class Item
  {
    [Key]
    public int IID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string App { get; set; }
...
```

After declare model - build solution, i create controller by choose "**MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework**", select **model**, **data context**, check to "**Generate views**, **reference script libraries**", click "**Add**". 
And this is my problem:
[There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrive metadata for '...Models.Item'. Sequence contains no matching element'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaMcz.png)

I retry but this time, i remove all attribute so it's work. Anyone can tell me what can i do for declare attribute in each column like case 1, i need to do this because i want to compile this model file to ddl file to reuse another project. Many many thanks for your help <3

Comment: please post your dbcontext class.

Comment: thank for your comment. i was found the awnser, the problem is i declare wrong typeName. instead of `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]`, i using `[Column(TypeName = "varchar")] [StringLength("50")]` and it's work :D